# C# Traversing MySqlDataReader to check for null values

Tags: charts

I am trying to traverse the MySqlDataReader stream in order to search for null values and then place those null values as "0". This is because I would like to plot these values onto a chart in C#. However if there is a null value it would not generate the output.

May you please assist?

Code:

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    datevalue = myReader.GetString("RunDate").Remove(2);

                    timevalue = myReader.GetString("ExactTarget");
                    itimevalue = DateTime.Parse(timevalue);

                    dhours = itimevalue.Hour;
                    dminutes = itimevalue.Minute;
                    dseconds = itimevalue.Second;

                    dtotaltime = dhours + (dminutes / 60) + (dseconds / (60 * 60));

                              this.chart1.Series["ExactTarget"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("RunDate").Remove(2), dtotaltime);


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Do you think I should alter this from the MySql query? Or can it be done programmatically here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved ... handled this through the Sql query from the input. Programmatically it would have zapped the performance of the application.